# Run AngularJS directive function through Karma Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm fairly new to angular/karma testing.

I have a function within my directive the generates a modal upon the selection of an appropriate date selection withn another modal (I.e. a user clicks a button, a modal appears prompting the user to select a certain date; when the user submits a date - a subsequent 'Response' Modal is shown. I have laid out pseudo-code below for simplicity sake:

```
specifyDate = function(object) {
  var modal = dateSelectionModalService.showDateSelectionModal()

  modal.result.then(function (date) {
   dateSelectionModalService.showResponseModal();
}
```

The code works and I'm currently trying to establish a karma test based on the response modal being generated when a date is submitted.

My thinking for that particular test so far has been:

```
it('should show the response modal when date selected', function() {

   var defferedModalResponse = $q.defer(),
   modalResult = {result: deferedModalResponse.promise};
   spyOn(dateSelectionModalService, 'showResponseModal')

  (dateSelectionModalService, 'showDateSelectionModal').and.returnValue(modalResult);

   expect(datePickerModalService.showChangedEffectiveDateModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Am I thinking along the right way? Or is there something completely different as to how I should look at this?

Comment: Please, revise your code. `(dateSelectionModalService, 'showDateSelectionModal')` is syntactic error, and there's no `showChangedEffectiveDateModal`.